# What is the meaning of 'to summon the future'?

Tags: meaning, quotes, cinema

There is a quote from STAR TREK

> *Mirror Spock:* One man cannot summon the future.
> *Capt. James T. Kirk:* But one man can change the present.

What is the meaning of *summon* here?
*predict* or *shape* or maybe something else.

P.S. Curiously, the question is triggered by trying to translate a phrase from Rammstein's 'Die Zeit':

> Zukunft kann man nicht beschwören...

Comment: A translation of *beschwören* would be "to conjure (up)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the definitions provided by [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/summon) is:

> to ***call into being*** through the use of one's inner resources or powers

So the sentence

> One man cannot ***summon*** the future.

means that a man cannot call the future into the present. One cannot make things *to be* happen in the present (just as one cannot turn back time). Note that this verb is often used with a subject designating a higher authority or power (divinity, a court, king, parliament etc. See this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_NOUN%20summoned&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3))

But you can, however, ***summon*** memories, as Shakespeare shows in his *[Sonnet 30](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/sonnets/sonnet_view.php?Sonnet=30)*:

> When to the sessions of sweet silent thought
> ***I summon up
> remembrance*** ***of things past***,
> I sigh the lack of many a thing I
> sought,
> And with old woes new wail my dear time's waste.

Comment: This can be interpreted '[ so ] the sentence means A, but it could also mean B'. 'To summon is also to remember or **imagine** something' [[CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/summon)]